# Facebook Image not loading on jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to combine the [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) with the Facebook Graph API.

The problem is that pictures won't load in my autocomplete.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTT5C/) to see the code.

The code works, the image tag is correctly created, and the images exist when you surf to them... I just cannot get them to load in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Apparently the code works fine. I get problems in Chrome 17 though, not sure what that problem is. But as fas as the code goes: it works.

Comment: It was working great for me :)

Comment: They load correctly for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: How weird. I'm using Chrome 17 and it does not work.
Tested FF 9 and IE 9 and it worked for me their too. Can somebody test Chrome for me?

Comment: Anything in the console at all? CTRL + SHIFT + J

Comment: Nope, everything looks great in the html-code, no JS-errors.

Comment: Does it attempt to even download the image in the "Network" tab? What's the response...

Comment: @eth0: It does download the images, as I see them loaded in the resource tab

Comment: @papaiatis Thnx for testing it out

Comment: I've just tested Chrome 17 too and works for me too. Interesting.

Comment: Ok, case closed I guess. Thank you for the answers. How do I end this question if there is no answer?